# With AngularDart how can I create something approximating a directive (w/ v0.12.0)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Hello I've been doing angularjs dev for a while and thought I'd take a look at angulardart. I am trying to determine if a component *must* specify a template. My problem seems to stem from the fact that the documentation is several releases behind the current release.

Things like NgDirective and NgController seem to have been deprecated. I am given the impression from various sources that everything is supposed to be lumped into @Component (but I'm probably wrong). So I can write a simple component okay but what's troubling me is components applied to elements always seem to replace their inner html with null or a template if one is provided.

That is quite a different from a angularjs directive which only did that if u explicitly told it too and by default kept any inner content defined in the html. How can I have a Component preserve what child content I entered into the html?

Comment: Seems I need to use @Decorator for that type of functionality.

Comment: I read somewhere (a while ago) that Decorator replaces Directive but I don't know about the current status.